# How to re-connect to netty channel after disconnect?

Tags: java, netty

I am connecting to a host/port as follows :-

boostrap.connect(host,port).sync().channel();

Once it gets connected. I shutdown the server at specified host/port.

Then again i try to connect using boostrap.connect(host,port).sync().channel();
It throws ClosedChannelException.
Any one has idea Why it is throwing this exception even when I am trying to establish new channel ?

I donot use same boostrap instance, i create new for every re-connect and new pass instance of Channel initializer like :-
Boostrap b = new Boostrap()
b.group(1).channel(NioSocketChannel).handler(new ChannelInitializer());

In ChannelInitilizaer I pass new instance of ChannelHandler.

Please suggest.

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19763953/3199508

Comment: please look into this code for reconnection https://gist.github.com/ochinchina/e97606fd0b15f106c91c